# Ionic 1 input get weird after special characters are introduced

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Essentially, I don't have complex code but when using input fields in my Ionic 1 app there is an error that screws up the text in the field after I use anything that isn't alphanumeric. So typing in the email address 'o@o.com' (each letter chronologicaly) in a field displays like this:

o
o@
oo@
oo@.
oo@..
oo@..o
oo@..om

This is happening on an android device. I don't know whether or not it works on an ios device. It doesn't happen in an emulator or in ionic serve --lab. I've tested the ionic templates and it breaks with those projects too. So I don't think it matters what my specific code looks like but here it is:

```
<form ng-submit="doLogin()">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.email">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've recently started working in Ionic 2 in the last couple months, and don't know if that has had negative effects on Ionic 1 apps (I know they say it doesn't but this wasn't a problem in the past). What do you all think of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sat for a while until I was forced to update my JDK and do some updates in Android SDK Manager. Then it seemed to work fine.